# Passing Japanese Character to PhP file

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I make a simple PhP program

```
<?php

echo $_GET['ID'];
?>
```

Then I call

```
http://localhost/testGetID/?ID=%E6%AD%A4%E5%8E%9F%E7%90%86%E6%98%AF%E5%9C%A8
```

This is what I got:
æ­¤åŽŸç†æ˜¯åœ¨

What should I do so I show up actual chinese characters? The chinese characters will be ID for my databases by the way.

Comment: post the code where you handle / display the characters

Comment: I did post the code but it doesn't show up because I didn't put it on blog tag.

Comment: edit the question and post it again so we can see it using the code indentation

Comment: already done before you asked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add this line to your `<head></head>` section `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
2. use `urldecode()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` function
3. encode the ID with `base64_encode()` and then decode it with `base64_decode()`

Comment: Actually the 1st solution work. For me to use mb_convert_encoding what would be the from and to of the encoding? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you specify your charset information in the head section, you might use `mb_convert_encoding()` function to reduce multibyte charset to a single byte charset. I don't know the details well for Chinese single-byte charsets to use in  `$to` variable. But the `$from` variable would be UTF-8 in your case.

Comment: actually I used utf-8 on to $to. I left the $from empty, which I don't feel comfortable with.

Comment: Use the first solution if you plan on using UTF-8 in your files, which I recommend. The second solution is a workaround to use multibyte strings in single byte charset encodings. The third one is another workaround to pass data from source to destination. Only one is needed to solve your problem.

Comment: Well the third one will work with the first one applied too. :) so the first one is the most usable answer here.

Comment: The issue is I am trying to use the result to database. I make the program that simply display the character so you have easier time answering that.

Comment: use UTF8 on every platform then. database collations, encodings, page encodings, file types etc. there won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
Your php code/chinese characters go here.
<body>
</body>
</html>
```